# Display multiple fields from POJO object in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list of a POJO in an Android app and I am currently displaying one of the fields in a listview/listitem like so:

```
List<NotificationItem> notifItems;
// snip, populate

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.notification_item, notifItems);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And it is my understanding that the listivew or adapter uses the toString of the POJO, which is

```
public String toString() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    return _notificationTitle + " | " + dateFormatter.format(_notificationReceivedDate);
}
```

R.id.notificationitem is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
```

So far so good, but what I want to do is add elements to the notificationitem layout file and then update the Java code to populate the new fields.

How is this done? I don't really understand how the adapter knows/puts the toString value into the one field in the notificationitem.

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter.

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<POJO> { ...` and override its `onBind()` method, extra bonus: override `matches()` method if you want easy item filtering

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NotificationItem {
    //your fields here
}
//-----------------------
public class NotifAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<NotificationItem> data;

    public NotifAdapter(Context context, List<NotificationItem> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout,parent, null);
        TextView tx = convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_widget_inside_row_layout);
        tx.setText(data.yourDataPropery);
        return convertView;
    }
}
// In your activity
NotifAdapter adapter = new NotifAdapter(this, ArrayList<NotificationItem>);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```